# Update Dexie entry if unique key exists

Tags: javascript, indexing, indexeddb, dexie

I set up a table with a unique key like:

```js
let db = new Dexie("myDB");
db.version(1).stores({
  myTable : "++id,&label"
});
db.put({label:"A",name:"Bob"});
```

I want to insert a new object with the label "A". But I get a ConstraintError because label "A" already exists.

`db.put({label:"A",name:"Mark"});`

In MySQL I would do something like:

`INSERT INTO myTable (label, name) VALUES ("A", "Mark") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET label=VALUES(label), name=VALUES(name)`

Can I do something similar with IndexedDB using Dexie? Keep in mind there might be multiple unique indexes, so simply searching for index "A" to see if it exists might not be a viable option.

Comment: `.put()` returns a promise, can you just catch the error and do the update there?

Comment: @Herohtar I can catch the error, but it doesn't tell me the primary key of the row that held the duplicate.

Comment: Get the entry, copy and modify, delete the entry, add the entry with fresh data. Still the simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no functionality like that in indexedDB, and therefore I assume there is also nothing in dexie which is basically just a wrapper library.

indexedDB will just fail with a constraint error every time you try to store an object.

You need to use `openCursor` or `get` or `openKeyCursor` to find if a record exists, and then decide whether to use `put`. This will always involve two requests, even if you use `openCursor` and `cursor.update`, as `cursor.update` is just syntactic sugar for `put`.

Alternatively, I suppose you could just shift your perspective, and say that various puts may fail. Or restructure your object store and constraints. This particular type of issue is definitely a criterion in deciding how to store objects.

Comment: Alright, just gonna drop the auto increment index for said table then, but this seems like a fundamental shortcoming in indexeddb. If half the userbase of said web app didn't use Firefox I'd probably just use WebSQL :/